# How to provide https requests in EC2 Instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, hosting

I have deployed a python script which works using Uvicorn. I have installed nginx on my Ubuntu ec2 instance and installed all requirements to run my script. I have created a file named as **Hosting** in directory ***/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*** . My file looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 12.34.56.78 (this is an pseudo IP);
  

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            }
  }
```

When I run my script using this command, it starts serving the application on Ip **12.34.56.78**

> gunicorn3 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker **app:app**

To access the API urls I have to use http://12.34.56.78 (not https) and it works correctely but I want it to work on *https://12.34.56.78* (with https) .

I tried to change the **Hosting** file and change the *listen 80* to *listen 443*

```
server {
    listen 443 <- made changes;
    server_name 12.34.56.78 (this is an pseudo IP);


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            }
  }
```

But unfortunately it is not working, I changed the Inbound secrity rules in AWS to accept https and http but it's not working too.

When I try to go https://12.34.56.78 , the webpage says

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection 12.34.56.78 sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Could anyone find the mistake ? Thank you in advance

Comment: It has to read `listen 443 ssl;`. Also note that putting an IP into `server_name` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you for answering sir, I made the require changed but not worked, what should be the value of server_name ? I followed an youtube tutorial and he placed the public IP address value in server name , and it was working for him, what should be the changes ?

Comment: What does "not worked" mean exactly?

Comment: Now the webpage saying "This site can’t be reached12.34.56.78 unexpectedly closed the connection."